# How to get a religion when all religions are occupied?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civilization VI, how can I get a religion, while all religions are already occupied by other (computer) players?

I captured a few computer player capitals, but it doesn't give me the religion.
I currently have 6,911 faith points, which are quite useless as far as I can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "getting" the religion. Once a religion is founded, its founder is set in stone - this is the civilization that can expand the religion's beliefs with Apostles, benefit from its Founder Belief, and win a Religious Victory with it. You can't become the religion's founder by any means.

However, this does not mean that foreign religions are useless to you. Their Follower Beliefs - including most of the general city buffs and religious structures - work for you just as they do for their founders. If a foreign religion arrives in your cities with a Follower Belief you like, you can spend Faith on Missionaries to expand it through the rest of your cities.

There are also general Faith expenses that you can use even without a religion, the most important of which is patronage. You can spend either Gold or Faith (but not a combination!) to make up the missing points needed to acquire a Great Person. In effect, you can use Faith to buy Great People of your choice, with the cost depending on how close you are to earning them normally.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to try to spread some religion (I have several types as I conquered some cities), and good to know about the great people buying feature.

Comment: You can also "get" the religion of someone else via conquering them and their holy city.

Comment: @n_plum I captured 3 of my competitors (all of their cities), but still don't have the religion itself.

Comment: You don't technically own it and aren't capable of reforming it. but you can create religious units of those religions and spread it yourself

Comment: @n_plum You don't need the holy city to do that - you can create religious units from any city that follows that religion (and has an upgraded Holy Site district). It will show the icon of the religion that the unit will spread in the purchase menu.

Comment: Except for great people patronage, you could spend faith points on city center buildings (if you are a suzerain of Valetta city-state), on builder,settlers and traders (GS expansion, golden age and Monumentality dedication) or bying land units if you've built grand master's chappel (GS)